# Unity2d: flip the y-component of transform.up

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I am very new to Unity. I am wondering how you would flip the y-component of transform.up. Context is that when object A hits a wall at the bottom/top, I would like it to travel the opposite direction of the y-axis. Alternatively, if object A hits a wall at the sides, i'd want to flip the x-component. So far, rotating 180 doesn't really reflect that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To flip

```
transform.up
```

you simply do:

```
-transform.up
```

A very basic up and down movement script you can test:

```
public class UpDownMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    int dir = 1;

    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position.y > 6.5f) dir = -1;
        if (transform.position.y < .5) dir = 1;

        if (transform.position.y < 6.5f && dir == 1)
            transform.position += -transform.up * Time.deltaTime * 5f;
        else
            transform.position += transform.up * Time.deltaTime * 5f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For local transofrmation use `transform.up * -1`  and for World use `Vector3.down`